# How to Return a SAFEARRAY from C# to COM(Javascript)?

Tags: c#, javascript, html, com

This Is my C# code my `GetChannelSample()` method `return an int[] array` I want to access this array into javascript but I dont know how to do this?

```
[Guid("4794D615-BE51-4a1e-B1BA-453F6E9337C4")] 
[ComVisible(true)]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
class Test:IComOjbect
{
            private int[] nAllData;
            public int[] GetChannelSample(int channelIndex)
            {
             //Some Logic here that will return integer type of array{1,12,15,48,1452,45,100,01}
              return nAllData;
            }
}

[Guid("4B3AE7D8-FB6A-4558-8A96-BF82B54F329C")]
[ComVisible(true)]
public interface IComOjbect
 {
    [DispId(0x10000008)]
    int[] GetChannelSample(int channelIndex);
 }
```

I for this I created the COM Component using Gacutil and Regasm command so that com componant can easly access in javascript but I dont know how to return if my C# method retrn int[] array and access it using javascript array.

Answer (score 0):

If this is some kind of the handler you can just serialize the result to JSON and deserialize it on the client:

using JSON.NET

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(GetChannelSample(channelIndex));
this.Context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
this.currentContext.Response.Write(json);
```

or Javascript Serializer

```
JavascriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
string json = ser.Serialize(GetChannelSample(channelIndex));
this.Context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
this.currentContext.Response.Write(json);
```

on the client:

```
function onAjaxSuccess (data){
    var myArr = JSON.parse(data);
}
```